# if strings are equal - if statement

Tags: c++

I'm parsing arguments from the command line

## code

```
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    cout << i << " " << argv[i] << "\n";
    if(argv[i] == "-width"){
        cout << " width = " << argv[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

## command

```
./txtbin test.jpg -width 100 out.jpg
```

## result

```
1 test.jpg
2 -width
3 100
4 out.jpg
```

why is this line inside the if-statement not printed?

```
cout << " width = " << argv[i] << "\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `argv` is an array of pointers to char and you can't just compare *a pointer to char and a string literal*. To solve your problem, you can convert both to `std::string` like this:

```
if(std::string(argv[i]) == "-width")
```

Otherwise, you can use `strcmp` to compare *C strings* as shown [in the docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

Comment: The second `std::string` is redundant and converting to a string seems a little heavy as `strcmp` exists to work on c style strings

Comment: @NathanOliver, I was just adding this into my answer when I saw your comment (I was busy searching for a link so didn't include it at first).